# iOS - Detecting color combination on camera feed

Tags: ios, opencv, augmented-reality

I need to detect something like a barcode but colored on live video (I don't necessarily need tracking, it is optional).I could use OpenCV but I thought it is worth a try asking here. The problem with openCV is that I am not very familiar with the whole concept of image processing. The other problem is that I use swift in most of the time, and however I could write an Obj-C wrapper with the help of google, the fact that OpenCV is written in C++ does not help at all, so maybe it would take too much time to use OpenCV.

Do you know any SDK-s that could help me in that? (It is not a problem if it is not free)

**EDIT:**

To be clear. By "something like a barcode" I mean that it is colored and instead of the width of the bars the colors are what metter.

Comment: You say "something like a barcode". Is it a barcode? In that case there are libraries in iOS for that. If not a barcode could you an example of what it looks like?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Question edited.